# If The order of $G$ is $pm$ and $p$ is prime such that If $H$ is normal to $G$ with order $p$ show that H is characteristic

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

I will be grateful for your help 
If The order of $G$ is $pm$ and $p$ is prime such that If $H$ is normal to $G$ with order $p$ show that H is  characteristic

Comment: I assume that you also want $m$ to be coprime to $p$?

Comment: p prime and p∤m

Comment: Ok, are you familiar with Sylow's theorems?

Comment: yes but not how to apply well to the problem , I mean , I know I must find an automorphism and show that it is invariant and that the automorphism is again in the subgroup , but then my question is , what automorphism should I use?

Comment: No, you need to show that it is invariant under any automorphism. But note what the Sylow theorems says about the number of subgroups of order $p$ in this group. And if you restrict an automorphism to a subgroup of order $p$, what can the image be?

Comment: the image  of the  automorphism under H must be H?

Comment: That is what you are trying to show, yes. So why must it be the case here?

Comment: Subgroups of order p are Sylow p-subgroups in G, so φ(H) must be conjugate to H, also H is normal to G ¿mean that x(φ(H))(x`-1)=H? ¿that means φ(H) is contained in H?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the following holds.

**Proposition** Let $G$ be a finite group, and $N \unlhd G$, such that gcd$(|N|,|G:N|)=1$. Then $N$ is a characteristic subgroup.

**Proof** Let $\phi \in Aut(G)$. Since $\phi$ is bijective, $|N|=|\phi(N)|$. Now let us have a look at image of $\phi(N)$ in the quotient $G/N$: $\phi(N)N/N \cong \phi(N)/(N \cap \phi(N))$. So we see that $|\phi(N):(N \cap \phi(N)|$ divides both $|\phi(N)|$ and $|G:N|$, hence $|\phi(N):(N \cap \phi(N)|=1$, that is, $\phi(N) \subseteq N$, and since the orders of these subgroups are equal we get $\phi(N)=N$.